# Check whether letters of word are in alphabetical order

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem

Write a function/program that accepts a string of lower/uppercase letters [A-Za-z] as input, that checks whether the occuring letters are unique and in alphabetical order (ignoring lower and uppercase) or not. The output must be truthy if they are unique and in alphabetical order and falsy if not.

Here some testcases

```
a                           true
abcdefGHIjklmnopqrSTUVWXyz  true     
aa                          false
puz                         true
puzz                        false
puzZ                        false
puZ                         true
PuZ                         true
pzu                         false
pzU                         false
abcdABCD                    false
dcba                        false
```

If you want, run your program on all words of a wordlist like [this one](http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/wordlists/english/wordlist/wordsEn.txt) and and post some interesting ones =).

#### Score

Lowest number of bytes wins.

Comment: Weak test cases. (See [my comment](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47201/check-whether-letters-of-word-are-in-alphabetical-order/47634#comment111854_47318/richard-a) on [Richard A](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/18406)'s [PHP answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47318).)

Comment: Does the alphabet loop? Should `za` be a truthy value?

Comment: No, the alphabet begins with `a` and ends with `z`.

Comment: You should have some test cases that aren't in alphabetical order

Comment: @JoKing I added some.

Comment: @manatwork I don't really know PHP, can you suggest some explicit examples?

Comment: Your freshly added test cases are Ok, they make it obvious that the PHP solution lacks the order check part of the task.

Comment: @manatwork Great, thanks for the rapid answer after you had to wait four years for mine:)

Comment: Is it _guaranteed_ that input consist of a single word? Do we need to filter input for alphabetic characters?

Comment: Yes, the string only consists of letters in `[a-zA-Z]`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## CJam, 8 bytes

```
lel_$_&=
```

[Here is a test harness](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F%7B%0A%0Ael_%24_%26%3D%0A%0Ap%7D%2F&input=a%0AabcdefGHIjklmnopqrSTUVWXyz%0Aaa%0Apuz%0Apuzz%0ApuzZ%0ApuZ%0APuZ) for all examples in the challenge. This returns `0` or `1` (which are falsy and truthy, respectively, in CJam).

And [here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F%7B%0A%0Ael_%24_%26%3D%0A%0A%7D%2C%20N*) is a script to filter the word list in the question (takes a few seconds to run). You'll have to copy the word list into the input field manually, because it's too long for a permalink.

### Explanation

```
l        "Read input.";
 el      "Convert to lower case.";
   _$    "Get a copy and sort it.";
     _&  "Remove duplicates (by computing the set intersection with itself).";
       = "Check for equality with original (lower case) word.";
```

Answer (score 21):

## Regex (any flavor), 55 bytes

Some people don't consider regex to be a programming language, but it's been used before, and it's not close to being the shortest.

```
^a?b?c?d?e?f?g?h?i?j?k?l?m?n?o?p?q?r?s?t?u?v?w?x?y?z?$
```

I've added one byte for the `i` (case-insensitive) flag. This is very straightforward and might be shorter to generate on the fly.

If regex alone are not allowed, you can use this 56-byte [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina) program suggested by Martin Büttner:

```
i`^a?b?c?d?e?f?g?h?i?j?k?l?m?n?o?p?q?r?s?t?u?v?w?x?y?z?$
```

Running this on the wordlist linked above yielded 10 6-letter words in alphabetical order.

> ["abhors", "almost", "begins", "begirt", "bijoux", "biopsy", "chimps", "chinos", "chintz", "ghosty"]

Comment: You can use [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina) instead of ES6 if someone complains that regex is not a language: ``i`^a?b?c?d?e?f?g?h?i?j?k?l?m?n?o?p?q?r?s?t?u?v?w?x?y?z?$``

Comment: @MartinBüttner I'd forgotten about Retina. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinBüttner According to the META (http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/what-are-programming-languages/2073#2073) Regexes can be 'seen' somewhat as a programming language.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I know. And in fact that definition was specifically chosen to make sure it doesn't rule out regex. But some people still regularly complain, because you can't use regex like any other language.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Those who complain can go to a place called META and look for it. Why no one visits such a beautiful place full of questions that solve most issues?

Comment: If you want a dynamically generated version, there's a decently short and readable Haskell version with `'^':concatMap(:"?")['a'..'z']++"$"` (34 bytes) or a somewhat golfed Ruby version with `?^+(?a..?z).to_a.join(??)+?$` (28 bytes).

Comment: (Correction to my last comment: Ruby code should end with `+"?$"`. Use `/#{?^+(?a..?z).to_a.join(??)+"?$"}/` to put it in a Regexp if needed.)

Comment: Looks like 54 bytes to me. (26*2+2)

Comment: @Eric I added a byte for the `i` flag.

Comment: @hsl Oh, duh, you even wrote that. I feel smrt.

Answer (score 20):

## Python 3, 44 bytes

```py
*s,=input().lower()
print(sorted(set(s))==s)
```

A simple approach - check uniqueness, check sortedness.

Comment: Can you explain what `*s,=...` does?

Comment: @flawr This is called 'starred assignment'. In this code, it simply converts the right side into a list. It's the same as `s=list(input().lower())`.

Comment: @flawr As Jakube says, here it's just converting input into a list of chars. In general it's a special assignment syntax which lets you do things like `x,*y = [1, 2, 3, 4]`, which assigns 1 to `x` and `[2, 3, 4]` to `y`.

Comment: @mbomb007 `*s,=` *is* `list(s)`... [link](http://repl.it/c50/1)

Comment: You can do `{*s}` instead of `set(s)` to save 2 bytes.

Comment: @mbomb007 Python 3.5.0 came after this answer

Comment: Ah, right. Nevermind.

Answer (score 12):

## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>52</s> <s>42</s> 39 bytes

```
0>i:1+?v1n;
? )'`':/'@'v
0v?){:-<'`'/;n
```

This type of question is one of the few types that ><> is pretty comfortable with, since we only need to deal with one char at a time.

### Explanation

Don't get lost! There's a lot of wrapping here.

```
0            Push 0. We'll be mapping a-z to 1-26, so 0 will be smaller than everything

(loop)
i            Read a char of input
:1+? 1n;     If there's no more input, print 1
:'`')?       If the char is bigger than backtick...
  '`'          Push backtick  (which is one before 'a'), else...
  '@'          Push an @ sign (which is one before 'A')
-            Subtract, mapping a-z to 1-26
:{)?         If the new char is bigger than the previous char...
               Repeat from the beginning of the loop, else...
  0n;          Print 0
```

### Previous solution, 42 bytes

```
0i:1+?v1n;n0/\!
?)'`':/'@'v
? ){:-<'`'/ vv
```

The interesting thing is that, despite appearing to have the same functionality, the alternative

```
0i:1+?v1n;n0\/!
?)'`':/'@'v
? ){:-<'`'/ ^^
```

*(The change is in the arrows and mirrors on the far right)*

actually gives *incorrect* results, due to ><>'s interpreter using a Python defaultdict. What happens is that, by traversing through the empty space at the end of the second row, 0s are implicitly placed into the blank spaces when ><> tries to access the cell. This then messes with the `?` conditional trampoline at the beginning of the same row, as the newly placed 0s are skipped rather than the `v` at the end.

Comment: I feel like you could save some bytes by only substracting 32 from lowercase letters rather than getting alphabetic index for all letters

Answer (score 9):

## Haskell, 52 Bytes

```
import Data.Char
and.(zipWith(>)=<<tail).map toLower
```

Usage: `(and.(zipWith(>)=<<tail).map toLower) "abcd"` which outputs `True`.

Answer (score 9):

## C, <strike>67 65 57</strike> 54 (52) characters

```cpp
f(char*s){int c,d=0;for(;(c=*s++)&&(c&~32)>(d&~32);d=c);return!c;}
```

a little shorter:

```cpp
f(char*s){int c,d=0;for(;(c=*s++)&&(c&~32)>d;d=c&~32);return!c;}
```

and even shorter:

```cpp
f(char*s){int d=32;for(;(*s|32)>d;d=*s++|32);return!*s;}
```

Here's a little test: http://ideone.com/ZHd0xl

After the latest suggestions here are still two shorter versions:

```cpp
// 54 bytes
f(char*s){int d=1;for(;(*s&=95)>d;d=*s++);return!*s;}

// 52, though not sure if valid because of global variable
d;f(char*s){d=1;for(;(*s&=95)>d;d=*s++);return!*s;}
```

Also this code relies on the fact, that in ASCII lowercase and uppercase only differ by the 5th bit (32) which I filter out. So this might not work with other encodings obviously.

EDIT: The latest version always sets the 5th bit as `|32` is shorter than `&~32`.

Comment: Good use of domain knowledge to handle the case sensitivity issue.

Comment: Save 2 by replacing the for loop with `for(;(*s&=95)>d;d=*s++);`.  And you can initialize `d` to `1` without changing the result, saving 1 more.  [See.](http://ideone.com/MnZ6Lx)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is considered legal in code golf, but `d;f(char*s){d=32;for...}` works, declaring `d` implicitly as a global int (which, in GCC, is a warning—"data definition has no type or storage class"—but not an error). This saves two bytes.

Comment: AShelly hm, didn't consider that. Your suggestion changes the original string though. But whatever, it's code golf :D
Also I'm not sure about WChargin's hint as d as a global variable would not really be part of the function.

Comment: I think the problem with the global is that it won't work the 2nd time the function is called.

Comment: Why not initialize `d` in the `for` loop rather than its own statement?  That way you save a `;`.

Answer (score 6):

## Ruby, 33

```ruby
->s{c=s.upcase.chars
c==c.sort|c}
```

Checks to see if the sorted unique characters are the same as all the characters.

Comment: Think you can get it a little shorter with `c==c.sort|c`

Comment: Ooh, I like that, that's clever. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

### Javascript (ES5), 101

```
function i(s){b=0;l=''.a
s.toUpperCase().split('').forEach(function(c){if(c<=l)b=1
l=c})
return!b}
```

### Improved to 87 by edc95:

upvote his comment :)

```
function i(s){return!s.toUpperCase().split(l='').some(function(c){return(u=l,l=c)<=u})}
```

*Btw, the test cases currently in OP are fulfilled if a program is only checking uniqueness, disregarding order.*

---

I cant write comments yet, so I'll answer some remarks here:

**@edc65:** Thanks! I tried rewriting it using `some()`, but I couldn't get a shorter solution, because even though it looks like it would enable me to get rid of the superflous b variable, you need to type "return" twice (same with `reduce()`), and you can't just return the comparison's result directly, because the last character needs to be saved after the comparison with it.

**@edc65:** That's a nice use of the comma operator for 87! I edited it into my answer for more visibility.

Comment: That's a better idea than mine. Using .some could be even better (52 with ES6)

Comment: You can remove the space between `return` and `!b` to save a char.

Comment: As is, just caring white space,96:`function i(s){b=0;l='';s.toUpperCase().split('').forEach(function(c){if(c<=l)b=1;l=c});return!b}`

Comment: The same, golfed more,92:`function i(s){s.toUpperCase(b=0).split(l='').forEach(function(c){if(c<=l)b=1;l=c});return!b}`

Comment: Using some(or every, same score),87:`function i(s){return!s.toUpperCase().split(l='').some(function(c){return(u=l,l=c)<=u})}`

Answer (score 5):

### Wolfram Mathematica, <strike>49</strike> 37 bytes

```
f[x_]:=(l=Characters[ToLowerCase[x]];Union[l]==l)
```

P.S. Shorter solution by Martin Büttner:

```
Union[l=Characters@ToLowerCase@#]==l&
```

Comment: `#⋃#==#&@*Characters@*ToLowerCase`

Comment: @alephalpha That is beautiful!

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, 90 bytes

Supplies the function `f :: String -> Bool`

```
import Data.List
import Distribution.Simple.Utils
f l=g$lowercase l
g l=sort l==l&&l==nub l
```

Usage (assuming it is saved as golf.hs). `...` is used to replace `ghci`'s verbose loading messages.

```
$ ghci golf.hs
...
*Main> f "as"
...
True
*Main> f "aa"
False
```

If someone has a `lowercase` method shorter than `import Distribution.Simple.Utils` then please comment.

Comment: Use `map toLower` from `Data.Char` instead of `lowercase`

Comment: Also: you can remove the parameter `l` at `f`, i.e. `f=g.lowercase` (or `f=g.map toLower` if you switch to `toLower`). Within `g` one comparison is enough: `g l=nub(sort l)==l`.

Answer (score 4):

## Pure Bash 4.x, 37

```
[[ ${1,,} =~ ^`printf %s? {a..z}`$ ]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYxLC4JQFIT391ccxCBBpdYh0osKWkRlD6Po6D0XLVPzQWTUXzcVWjTwzWKGGQdTr3x4fkCQEPIe8IhBpZQy0DSQ5OV4Md9L5eEA8qurqm8wPnA6x4kfZgJaqQkv1PXifZbheCzrpS@g3ZZNw@goSg8yj8LmsBa5XgRZklOTUJDSfyXwFwmf8SikEhk6Licxmc4u1@AWRvE9Wa2tzXb3LBgii/OipjG7MpstKuIir7CabX8wHDHuOsi@)

Input taken as a command-line parameter.  As per standard shell semantics, exit code 0 means true (alphabetic) and exit code != 0 means false (not alphabetic).

The printf creates the regex as in [@hsl's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47212/11259).  The input string is expanded to lowercase and compared against the regex.

---

Previous answer:

#### Bash + coreutils, 52

Straightforward solution:

```
a=`fold -1<<<${1,,}`
cmp -s <(sort -u<<<"$a")<<<"$a"
```

Comment: Note that this requires bash 4.x.

Comment: @MarkReed Yes. Noted.

Comment: I don't understand what the `${1,,}` is for, why can't you just use `$1`?

Comment: @pxeger it makes all letters lowercase - search for `,,` [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Answer (score 4):

## J, 17 bytes

Checks if the lowercase sorted `/:~` string equals `-:` the lowercase nub `~.` string.

```
   (/:~-:~.)@tolower

   NB. testing with the example inputs
   ((/:~-:~.)@tolower) every (1$'a');'abcdefGHIjklmnopqrSTUVWXyz';'aa';'puz';'puzz';'puzZ';'puZ';'PuZ'
1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1
```

As in J a 1-charater long "string" represented as a regular string (with quotes) is just a character atom not a real string I formatted the input appropriately so all input would be real strings. (In the example above I used `1$'a'`.)

Answer (score 4):

## MATLAB, <s>29</s> 27 bytes

Now for a one-liner which even makes sense outside of code-golf.

As an anonymous function (use as `o('yourstring')`)

```
o=@(s)all(diff(lower(s))>0)
```

I guess this function is pretty self-explanatory since it reads like a newspaper ad.

Previous version (29 bytes):

```
all(diff(lower(input('')))>0)
```

Input must be presented between `'` marks, e.g. `'Potato'`.

Answer (score 4):

### Golang (65 bytes)

Go is not a golf friendly language, also, i suck at golf...

```
func a(s[]byte)(bool){return len(s)<2||s[0]|32<s[1]|32&&a(s[1:])}
```

Run it here: http://play.golang.org/p/xXJX8GjDvr

*edit 106->102*

*edit 102->96*

*edit 96->91*

*edit 91->87*

*edit 87->65*

I beat the java version, I can stop for today

Answer (score 4):

## C (44 bytes)

`f(char*s){return(*s&=95)?f(s+1)>*s?*s:0:96;}`

Test it here: http://ideone.com/q1LL3E

Posting this because I can't comment yet, otherwise it would be a suggestion to improve the existing C answer because I completely stole the case-insensitive idea from the existing C answer.

Returns 0 if the string is not ordered, and a non-zero value if ordered.

Answer (score 4):

### VBA (161 bytes)

```
Function t(s As String)
t = 0
For i = 2 To Len(s)
a = Left(LCase(s), i)
    If Asc(Right(a, 1)) <= Asc(Right(a, 2)) Then Exit Function
Next
t = 1
End Function
```

Compares ascii value with previous letter in lowercase, return 0 (false) when its value is smaller / equal and exit function

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 3 bytes

```
ḷ⊆Ạ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pf/ahtw6Ompkcdy5VKikpTlfRqQMy0xJziVKXa04vK/z/csf1RV9vDXQv@/49WSlTSUUpMSk5JTXP38MzKzsnNyy8oLAoOCQ0Lj6isAkmCVBSUVkFIKBUFpkBkAJCMBQA)

The predicate succeeds if the input meets the requirements outlined and fails if it does not, printing `true.` or `false.` if run as a program.

```
       The input,
ḷ      lowercased,
 ⊆     is a not-necessarily-contiguous sub-list of
  Ạ    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".
```

The first version I came up with, not explicitly referencing the alphabet:

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 4 bytes

```
ḷ≠.o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pf/ahtw6Ompkcdy5VKikpTlfRqQMy0xJziVKXa04vK/z/csf1R5wK9/P//o5USlXSUEpOSU1LT3D08s7JzcvPyCwqLgkNCw8IjKqtAkiAVBaVVEBJKRYEpEBkAJGMB)

```
        The input,
ḷ       lowercased,
 ≠      in which every character is distinct,
  .     is the output variable,
   o    which sorted,
        is still the output variable.
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6) 54

Convert to uppercase, then to array and sort. If during sort two element are in the wrong order or equal, return 0 (falsy) else 1 (truthy)

**Edit** Shortened thx to @Optimizer (but still 2 more than the @Tamas solution implemented in ES6: `F=s=>[...s.toUpperCase()].every(c=>(u=l,l=c)>u,l='')`)

```js
F=s=>[...s.toUpperCase(x=1)].sort((a,b)=>a<b?1:x=0)&&x
```

**Test** in Firefox / FireBug console

```js
;['a','abcdefGHIjklmnopqrSTUVWXyz','aa','puz','puzz','puzZ','puZ','PuZ']
.map(w=>w+' '+F(w))
```

> ["a 1", "abcdefGHIjklmnopqrSTUVWXyz 1", "aa 0", "puz 1", "puzz 0", "puzZ 0", "puZ 1", "PuZ 1"]

Comment: `s=` does not seem to be required...

Comment: @Optimizer right, it was a first try when at last i compared the original (uppercased) and the sorted

Answer (score 3):

## C# 6, 18 + <s>82</s> 76 = 94 bytes

Requires (18 bytes):

```c#
using System.Linq;
```

Code (76 bytes):

```c#
bool a(string s)=>(s=s.ToLower()).Distinct().OrderBy(x=>x).SequenceEqual(s);
```

C# 6 supports lambdas to define a function, which is useful for golfing.

Non-C# 6 version:

```c#
bool a(string s){return (s=s.ToLower()).Distinct().OrderBy(x=>x).SequenceEqual(s);}
```

Ungolfed code:

```c#
bool IsInAlphabeticalOrder(string s)
{
    s = s.ToLower();
    return s.Distinct()
            .OrderBy(x => x)
            .SequenceEqual(s);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### J, 21 characters

This is too long. The argument must have rank `1`, i.e. it must be a string or vector.

```
*/@(<=~.;/:~)@tolower
```

- `tolower y` – `y` in lower case.
- `/:~ y` – `y` in lexical order.
- `~. y` – the nub of `y`, that is, `y` with duplicates removed.
- `x ; y` – `x` and `y` put into boxes and then concatenated.
- `< y` – `y` put into a box.
- `x = y` – `x`  compared element-wise with `y`.
- `(< y) = (~. y) ; (/:~ y)` – a vector indicating if `y` is equal to its nub and itself sorted.
- `*/ y` – the product of the items of `y`, or its logical and if the items are booleans.
- `*/ (< y) = (~. y) ; (/:~ y)` – a boolean indicating the desired property for lowercase `y`.

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, 44 bytes

```js
s->(l=lowercase(s);l==join(sort(unique(l))))
```

This creates an anonymous function that takes a single argument `s`, converts it to lower case, and compares it to the unique sorted version of the string. It returns a boolean, i.e. `true` or `false`. If you want to test it out, assign it like `f=s->...` and then call `f("PuZ")`, etc.

Comment: Amen to that, @flawr. Thanks for the support.

Comment: I'm slightly late but you can [shave 3 bytes](https://tio.run/##jdLNSgMxEAfwe55iyCmBuuBVSMUPUG@CVqWlh3R3AltjNs0H1n0NwZNP54us2YiCh7bJKYff/IfJZB11K4@3gxKDP5oyLRa6e0VXS4/M86qqllwI37nAomk3EZnmfAjogwcBC0Ilhd1HTCG4iEmt6gbV1fXN@lm/mM5u3N397OHx6a2nfypXJLovMVEltU@JNvb0cN@kdrN/YfMiNi/oeVukbB9pyZj9rISN73t2fnFJ97OmXsnDcy4JIapzwMY1T3BrsQ7YcGgN5MWTUVvXmqANU1mlP/Lr4BTo1@c7UDgZLx9AJ7ks5/9gTtA0wzc)

Answer (score 3):

### k (6 bytes)

```
&/>':_
```

`&` returns true if both args are true

`/` modifies `&` to apply "over" a list, like a fold in functional languages

`>` greater than

`':` modifies `>` to apply "each-prior", so returns a vector of booleans stating which elements are greater than their predecessor

`_` makes it argument lower case

```
  _"puzZ"
"puzz"
  >':_"puzZ"
1110b
  &/>':_"puzZ"
0b
```

(`0b` means boolean false)

### q (13 bytes)

```
all(>':)lower
```

q is just syntactic sugar on k. `all` is defined as `&/`, and lower is `_`

Comment: Can you explain how this works?

Comment: This almost feels like cheating on other languages... Who needs function names, parentheses and semicolons? :)

Comment: @sanchises k has all of those things and they work pretty much the same way as in C style languages. It's just that this problem happens to be expressible as a single statement.

Answer (score 3):

## Perl 6, 35 bytes

```
{my@c=.uc.comb;@c eq@c.sort.unique}
```

This produces a callable block; if I could just assume that `$_` is already set to the desired word, I could delete the surrounding curly braces and lose two more bytes, but probably the only reasonable way to make that assumption would be to run it with `-n` and feed the word as standard input, which would add the two bytes right back.

Comment: Sure it does. `.uc.comb` doesn't rearrange anything, so if the uppercased and combed array is equal to the _sorted_ uppercased and combed array, that means it started out in sorted order.

Comment: right, it's checking the size of the intersection, which ignores order. Ok, updated.

Answer (score 3):

### Java 8 - <strike>90</strike> <strike>89</strike> <strike>87</strike> 85 chars

The idea here is to use a 'reduce' function that tracks the last char and "gives up" when it detects the sequence is not strictly ascending.

**golfed:**

```
int f(String s){return s.toLowerCase().chars().reduce(0,(v,c)->(v<0)?v:(c>v)?c:-1);}
```

**ungolfed:**

```
int f(String s){
    return s.toLowerCase()
            .chars()
            .reduce(0, (v,c) -> (v<0)? v : (c>v)?c:-1);
}
```

**example:**

```
System.out.println(new Quick().f("abc"));
System.out.println(new Quick().f("aa"));
System.out.println(new Quick().f("abcdefGHIjklmnopqrSTUVWXyz"));
System.out.println(new Quick().f("puZ"));
System.out.println(new Quick().f("Puz"));
System.out.println(new Quick().f("cba"));
```

**output:**

```
99
-1
122
122
122
-1
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 37 bytes

```r
all(diff(utf8ToInt(scan(,''))%%32)>0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZptWmpdckpmfp1Gho1CcnJiHENDT09Os0Kz@n5iTo5GSmZamUVqSZhGS75lXogFSqKGjrq6pqapqbKRpZ6D5v5YrTUMpMSk5JTXN3cMzKzsnNy@/oLAoOCQ0LDyiskpJEyRfUFoVBWGBVDo6Obsoaf4HAA)

Posting since this is substantially different and shorter than [Michal's R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47272/86301).

Converts the letters to ASCII codepoints with `utf8ToInt`, then takes modulo 32 so that lower and upper letters are converted to the same numbers 1...26. Computes the pairwise differences, and checks that they are all positive.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 27

@hsl's regexp dynamically build.

```
#!perl -p
$"="?";@x=a..z;$_=/^@x?$/i
```

Also we can do a reverse match: convert the input into a regexp: `PuZ` => `.*p.*u.*z.*` and then match this to a string of letters in alphabetical order. Result - also 27 characters.

```
#!perl -lp
$_=join(s//.*/g,a..z)=~lc
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 50 bytes

```
f=lambda x:sorted(set(x.lower()))==list(x.lower())
```

Try online here: http://repl.it/c5Y/2

Answer (score 2):

## PHP (<s>89</s> <s>76</s> <s>72</s> 63 bytes)

I'm pretty horrible at golfing, but I thought I'd give it a shot.

```
<?=(join(array_unique(str_split($a=strtolower($argv[1]))))==$a)+0;
```

I had to cast the output to an integer, since booleans aren't printed in php.

I was able to remove the echo by using `<?=`, I also removed the `$b`.

**[edit]**

Removed the space after `<?=` and followed manatwork's suggestion to cut 4 bytes.

Also, replacing the implode with join and omitting the glue parameter saved another 9 bytes. Thanks manatwork.

Comment: You can also force a boolean into integer by adding 0 to it. `+0` is shorter than `(int)`.

Comment: Though this passes successfully the test cases provided in the question, it definitely not checks for alphabetical order. For example it outputs 1 for “xa”.

Comment: There is an alias for `implode()`, with shorter name: `join()`. And the first parameter is optional, defaulting to empty string.

Comment: @manatwork There is too, completely missed it. Thank you.

Comment: @manatwork I see it doesn't do alphabetical order... which I find weird, `array_unique` should sort the array.

Comment: I count 63 bytes. Forgot to count the tag?

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 43 bytes

```python
lambda s:eval('"%s"'%'"<"'.join(s.lower()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHYKrUsMUdDXUm1WEldVV3JRkldLys/M0@jWC8nvzy1SENTU/N/QVFmXolGmoZSYlJySmqau4dnVnZObl5@QWFRcEhoWHhEZZWSpiYXQlkikPsfAA)

Puts `<` symbols between all the letters (converted to lowercase), and then `eval`s it. Python's chained comparison operators are perfectly happy to evaluate the whole thing as one big boolean expression.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
⇩¨=‡Us
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4oepwqg94oChVXMiLCIiLCJhXG5hYmNkZWZHSElqa2xtbm9wcXJTVFVWV1h5eiAgXG5hYVxucHV6XG5wdXp6XG5wdXpaXG5wdVpcblB1WiJd)

### Explained

```
⇩¨=‡Us
⇩¨=    # is the lowercase version of the input invariant under:
  ‡Us  # uniquify and sort?
```

Comment: 3 bytes: `⇩Þ⇧` (filler)

Comment: Posted my three-byter [myself](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47201/check-whether-letters-of-word-are-in-alphabetical-order/251702#251702)

Answer (score 2):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 36 bytes

```
\S:-maplist(to_lower,S,L),sort(L,L).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/PybYSjc3sSAns7hEoyQ/Pie/PLVIJ1jHR1OnOL@oRMMHyNIDqkpITNDj4gJSSckpqWnuHp5Z2Tm5efkFhUXBIaFh4RGVVRD5glI4IwrCCIAxgFIIRTCxqlIYIxRhgaOTswuEl5KcBLMYSAMA)

Ungolfed:

```
\S :-
  maplist(to_lower, S, L), % convert each character code in S to lowercase, putting that in a list called L
  sort(L, L). % Does L sorted and uniquified equal L?
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP (52 bytes)

This is an answer based on @HSL's regex (sorry dude).

The idea is to grab the regex and generate it instead of having it hard-coded.

Here is the code:

```php
echo preg_match("@^".join('?',range(a,z))."?$@",$s);
```

Since this answer isn't entirely of my authority, I have marked it as "`Community Wiki`".

To use this, simply add a line before with `$s='String!';`.

Comment: If the string to parse should be provided in variable `$s`, then that should be `preg_match()`'s 2nd parameter. Which is 2 characters shorter.

Comment: @manatwork Oh god! Sorry the stupidity! I was distracted and wrote it without thinking. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

## Erlang, 51

```
f(S)->G=string:to_lower(S),ordsets:from_list(G)==G.
```

Uses an ordered set (analogous to `java.util.TreeSet`) to sort the characters and discard any duplicates. The new list is then compared with the input string.

Test Function:

```
test() ->
    [io:format("~p ~p~n", [S, f(S)]) || S <- ["a","abcdefGHIjklmnopqrSTUVWXyz","aa","puz","puzz","puzZ","puZ","PuZ"]].
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 96

```java
boolean a(char[]a){int i=-1,l=0;for(;++i<a.length;l+=i>0&&a[i]<=a[i-1]?1:0)a[i]|=32;return l<1;}
```

Pretty straightforward here. Just convert all to lower and compare each to the previous character.

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell, 37

```
-join(($x="$input")[0..26]|sort)-eq$x
```

Can be shortened by another byte by using command-line arguments instead of stdin (`$args` instead of `$input`).

Tricks used:

- PowerShell is case-insensitive by default, simplifying the check.
- Getting a `char[]` from the input is a bit shorter if we know an upper bound for the length `[0..x]` instead of `[char[]]`

Answer (score 1):

## Rebol - <s>26</s> 25

```
(s: input)= sort unique s
```

NB. Above works fine in Rebol 2.  However in Rebol 3 [`sort`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/sort.html) isn't case insensitive (yet) so for now it would need to be written has `(s: input)= sort lowercase unique s`

Answer (score 1):

## R, 62 Bytes

```
s=strsplit(tolower(word),"")[[1]]
all(s[order(unique(s))]==s)
```

This will throw a warning if there is a repeating character.

To avoid this, I inserted zeros to make both strings the same length. I assumed this is OK since we are only using letters and not numbers.

```
s <- strsplit(tolower(word), "")[[1]]
all(c(s[order(unique(s))],rep('0',length(s)-length(unique(s)) )) == s)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 69

```
(let[s(seq(.toLowerCase (read-line)))](= s(seq(apply sorted-set s))))
```

Run in the REPL, enter a string and press return. Prints `true` or `false`.  E.g.

```
user=> (let[s(seq(.toLowerCase (read-line)))](= s(seq(apply sorted-set s))))
puZ
true
user=> (let[s(seq(.toLowerCase (read-line)))](= s(seq(apply sorted-set s))))
puzz
false
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, <s>147</s> 145 bytes

```
function(a){b=[];a=a.toLowerCase().split('');while(a.length)b.push(a.pop().charCodeAt(0));while(c=b.pop()){if(c>=b[b.length-1])return 0}return 1}
```

An anonymous function that converts to lowercase, creates an array of char codes, then checks them from right to left.

Answer (score 1):

## Retina, 33 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
T`L`l
^
$_¶
O`\G.
D`\G.
^(.*)¶\1$
```

[**Try it online**](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=VGBMYGwKXgokX8K2Ck9gXEcuCkRgXEcuCl4oLiopwrZcMSQ&input=YWJjZGVmR0hJamtsbW5vcHFyU1RVVldYeXo)

Translate uppercase to lowercase, duplicate input, sort the first line, deduplicate first line, then check if the lines are equal.

Answer (score 1):

## C++14, <s>59</s> 58 bytes

-1 byte for `int` instead of `auto` in range-based for-loop.

As unnamed lambda returning via reference parameter. `64` (>0) for true, `0` for false. Input `s` may be `std::string` or `char[]`.

```c++
[](auto&s,int&r){int b=r=64;for(int c:s)r*=b<(c&=95),b=c;}
```

The `&=95` is from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47230/53667).

Ungolfed and usage:

```c++
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

auto f=
[](auto&s,int&r){
  int b=r=64;
  for(int c:s)
    r*=b<(c&=95),
    b=c;
}
;

int main(){
  std::string s;
  int r;
  s="ABC";
  f(s,r); std::cout << s << ", " << r << std::endl;
  s="AbC";
  f(s,r); std::cout << s << ", " << r << std::endl;
  s="ACB";
  f(s,r); std::cout << s << ", " << r << std::endl;
  s="AcB";
  f(s,r); std::cout << s << ", " << r << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 62 bytes (thank to Shaggy)

```
def a(w):
    v=w.lower()
    print v==''.join(sorted(set(v)))
```

I know I can not beat anyone but here is my solution.

PoC:
https://repl.it/repls/UnderstatedDecimalSales

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing the  missing part for me, I just updated my answer!

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 bytes

```
v ä< e
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=diDkPCBl&input=WyJhIgoiYWJjZGVmR0hJamtsbW5vcHFyU1RVVldYeXoiCiJhYSIKInB1eiIKInB1enoiCiJwdXpaIgoicHVaIgoiUHVaIl0KLW1R)

Explanation:

```
v         #Convert to all lowercase
  ä  e    #For every pair of consecutive letters:
   <      # Check that the second letter is later in the alphabet than the first
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 6 bytes

```
mδ_s▀=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z/33Jb44kfTGmz//1dPVOdST0xKTklNc/fwzMrOyc3LLygsCg4JDQuPqKwCSYJUFJRWQUgoFQWmQGQAkAQA)

### Explanation

```
m        explicit map (per character)
 δ       capitalize string
         these two commands transforms the input string to uppercase
  _      duplicate the uppercase string
   s     sort(array)
    ▀    unique elements of string
     =   check if equal to the uppercased input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 6 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```apl
(∧≡∪)⌊
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/X@NRx/JHnQsfdazSfNTT9T/tUduER719j/qmevo/6mo@tN74UdtEIC84yBlIhnh4Bv9P01FPVOdKU09MSk5JTXP38MzKzsnNyy8oLAoOCQ0Lj6isAsuC1RSUVkEpGB0FocFUAJACAA)

`(`…`)⌊` on the lowercase:

`∧≡∪` does the ascending sort match the unique?

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>29</s> 20 bytes

Saved 9 bytes thanks to *Jo King*

```
0\0=n;
!\i1+48*%:r)?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3yDGwDbPmksxJtNQ28RCS9WqSNP@///EpOSU1DR3D8@s7JzcvPyCwqLgkNCw8IjKKgA)

Comment: [20 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3yDGwDbPmksxJtNQ28RCS9WqSNP@///EpOSU1DR3D8@s7JzcvPyCwqLgkNCw8IjKKgA)

Comment: @JoKing: I was sure it could still be golfed, but 9 bytes is more than I'd thought was possible. I really like the `0=`. Need to remember that one for future golfs :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)+coreutils, 27 bytes

```bash
grep -Ei ^1`echo ?{a..z}?`$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P70otUBB1zVTIc4wITU5I1/BvjpRT6@q1j5B5f//RK7EpOSU1DR3D8@s7JzcvPyCwqLgkNCw8IjKKq7ERK6C0ioQBhNRQCKKK6A0CgA)

There was an earlier answer with pure Bash, but this one is cool because it saves space by making a much "worse" regular expression. The command substitution expands to the regular expression

```bash
^1?a? ?b? ?c? ?d? ?e? ?f? ?g? ?h? ?i? ?j? ?k? ?l? ?m? ?n? ?o? ?p? ?q? ?r? ?s? ?t? ?u? ?v? ?w? ?x? ?y? ?z?$
```

which accepts many things that we don't care about (1's at the beginning and spaces almost anywhere) but that's okay because it selects correctly when limited to things in the input specification. This lets us avoid a `printf %s` and just accept the spaces that Bash gives when it expands `?{a..z}?`

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 32 char, 64 bytes

```
{(k≡∪k)∧k≡k[⍋k←26∣¯1+(⎕A,⎕a)⍳⍵]}
```

how to use and test (note that "'a'" is a char type and ",'a'" is one type array chars):

```
  h←{(k≡∪k)∧k≡k[⍋k←26∣¯1+(⎕A,⎕a)⍳⍵]}
  h ,'a'
1
  h 'abcdefGHIjklmnopqrSTUVWXyz'
1
  h 'aa'
0
  h 'puz'
1
  h 'puzz'
0
  h 'puzZ'
0
```

Possible there is something more short.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 29 bytes

```ruby
->s{s=~/^#{[*?a..?z]*??}?$/i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664uti2Tj9OuTpayz5RT8@@KlbL3r7WXkU/s/Z/tFKiko5SYlJySmqau4dnVnZObl5@QWFRcEhoWHhEZRVIEqSioLQKQkKpKDAFIgOAZKxebmJBdU1FDVeBQlp0RSxX7X8A)

Returns 0 if in order, or false if not in order.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
lDêQ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/x@XwqsD//0NSi0sA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn3l/xyXw6sC/@v8T0xKTklNc/fwzMrOyc3LLygsCg4JDQuPqKziKigF4SiuACBO5AIpdHRydgEJg@WiuFKSkxK5QlKLS7gKqkqBOJQrMREA).

**Explanation:**

```python
      #  i.e. input: "Test"
l     # Convert the (implicit) input-string to lowercase
      #  STACK: ["test"]
 D    # Duplicate it
      #  STACK: ["test", "test"]
  ê   # Uniquify and sort the characters in the duplicated string
      #  STACK: ["test", "est"]
   Q  # Check if both strings are equal
      #  STACK: [0]
      # (after which the top of the stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>7</s> 5 bytes

```
ΠẊ>ma
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8f@5BQ93ddnlJv7//z9aKTEpOSU1LT1DSUepoLQKSAaURoHYVaUgdlUoRLxKKRYA)

Inspired by [caird's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217827/95126)

```
   m    # map over all letters of input:
    a   #  make lowercase
 Ẋ      # then for each pair
  >     #  test if R > L
Π       # and get the product of all the results.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
Œu<ƝẠ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opFKbY3Mf7lrw/3D7o6Y1//9Hc3EqJSrpKOAEygolRaWpIFVJySmpae4enlnZObl5@QWFRcEhoWHhEZVVQO0QVWANIKX4TFRWSEvMKQaZWFBahVsd3F6gKtzKUAyLIkpZFBF2BhClqqCqFJ8quJVVocQoA4Wvo5OzC1a1CGUpyUmJBP0ZCwA)

### How it works

```
Œu<ƝẠ - Main link. Takes a string S on the left
Œu    - Uppercase
   Ɲ  - Over overlapping pairs [a, b]:
  <   -   Is a < b?
    Ạ - True for all?
```

Answer (score 1):

## x86 machine code, 15 bytes

Hexdump:

```
33 c0 ac 24 5f 3a e0 73 05 8a e0 e2 f5 f9 c3
```

A function which receives a pointer to the string in `esi` and its length in `ecx`. Returns in `CF`.

Disassembly:

```
10011860 33 C0                xor         eax,eax  
10011862 AC                   lods        byte ptr [esi]  
10011863 24 5F                and         al,5Fh  
10011865 3A E0                cmp         ah,al  
10011867 73 05                jae         bad (1001186Eh)  
10011869 8A E0                mov         ah,al  
1001186B E2 F5                loop        my+2h (10011862h)  
1001186D F9                   stc  
1001186E C3                   ret
```

I had arrange the comparison in such a way that for "bad" strings the carry flag gets set to 0.

Test program (works in Visual Studio):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

__declspec(naked) char my()
{
    _asm
    {
        xor eax, eax;
    myloop:
        lodsb;
        and al, 0x5f;
        cmp ah, al;
        jae bad;

        mov ah, al;
        loop myloop;
        stc;
    bad:
        ret;
    }
}

__declspec(naked) bool __fastcall caller(const char*, size_t)
{
    _asm
    {
        push esi;
        mov esi, ecx;
        mov ecx, edx;
        call my;
        mov al, 0;
        adc al, 0;
        pop esi;
        ret;
    }
}

bool is_good(const char* s)
{
    printf("%s ", s);
    size_t l = strlen(s);
    return caller(s, l);
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", is_good("abd"));
    printf("%d\n", is_good("a"));
    printf("%d\n", is_good("abcdefGHIjklmnopqrSTUVWXyz"));
    printf("%d\n", is_good("aa"));
    printf("%d\n", is_good("puz"));
    printf("%d\n", is_good("puzz"));
    printf("%d\n", is_good("puzZ"));
    printf("%d\n", is_good("puZ"));
    printf("%d\n", is_good("PuZ"));
    printf("%d\n", is_good("pzu"));
    printf("%d\n", is_good("pzU"));
    printf("%d\n", is_good("abcdABCD"));
    printf("%d\n", is_good("dcba"));
}
```

It contains a function `caller` which translates calling conventions.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 8 bytes

```
qKrQ1S{K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v9C7KNAwuNr7/3@lxKTkFEclAA)

```
qKrQ1S{K
qKrQ1S{KQ  // Implicit input
 KrQ1      // Assign uppercase input to K
q    S{K   // Deduplicate K and sort it
q          // Is original K == deduplicated and sorted
```

Answer (score 1):

## Excel ms365, 45 bytes

```
=CONCAT(SORT(UNIQUE(MID(A1,ROW(1:26),1))))=A1
```

Comment: The formula fails if you copy it to other cells. I think you have to change it to `...ROW($1:26)...`,

Comment: @jdt one can assume input in cell `A1`. Since this is code-golf I'd not drag the formula down, a simple copy would do.

Comment: @JvdV sir, how are you getting to know about the bytes and is it necessary to mention while posting an answer?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya code-golf is not about making the most efficient answer. It's about the shortest answer in butes Each character is a byte in Excel. I usually count them [here](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter)

Comment: Oh sounds good sir, really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
⇩Þ⇧
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4oepw57ih6ciLCIiLCJhXG5hYmNkZWZHSElqa2xtbm9wcXJTVFVWV1h5eiAgXG5hYVxucHV6XG5wdXp6XG5wdXpaXG5wdVpcblB1WiJd)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 34 bytes

```julia
!x=all(diff(([x...].-'A').%32).>0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZBLa8MwEITv@hWbQIkEiejjrJAXpL0V2rQlJYd1JIESRVElG1z9edeuz7HmsLDDxwy7p8oafKibZlQLtJZKozWl3zXn/MBnk@WE8bunR8bn96zR1wAGjIOgUFrjVKSMQCucFiAgemtKanrLB@NK6yiCmMMIe3OBMapQtjsIAbTo5rgMlRozopxsEG6rwwgWR6n09vnldLYXd/U/4e199/H59Zt64J8kOJCj0UZFfJWGi1ogZSP2OWI/XPKaA3yqcoekXYboXrZcrTe3CXkscDDjDw)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 44 bytes

```cs
n=>n.Aggregate((a,b)=>a>1&a%32<b%32?b:'')>1
```

Can be 42 bytes if I return a SOH char for non-alphabetic and anything else for alphabetic.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcS7DoIwFADQuPYrWJQ2QRJ0U6lx8JU4GN8hLrelYBVvsYCJGr8dH8M5smjLQteTCuWgKK3G1BPGZDwJaww5@qM0tSqFUlEKnmAhBx60oNntDMS3oei5DZfxoO6TxFgF8kTvYB1wNDpz9FcK4o0ZY0yZv84zXVL3iC5jL7K3ulQLjYomFBjrk3cNBISMVTKdzc@X7Iomv9n1ZrvbHx5PAkDy6vnzL/oWkWUVfQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 93 bytes

```javascript
w=>new Set(w).size==w.length&&[...w.toLowerCase()].sort().join``==[...w.toLowerCase()].join``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcqxDsIgEIDh3adwamHw3gAXBzVxq5sx6ZUetRW5CkQiL48mbqbr9/8TvjBoP85x47inYlRJausorRuKIkkIYyalElhyQ7xV1QUAEkQ@cSK/w0BCXiGwj0LCxKNrW6UWn18sml1gS2B5EEbU2OmezP5wnO724Xh@@ub8zrWUq/8RcUEzdl8tHw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>30</s> 14 bytes

```perl6
{[<] .uc.ords}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzraJlZBrzRZL78opbj2vzVXWn6RgkZOZl5qsaZCNRdncWKlQppGXa5@TLC2viZX7f9EBdygpKg0lSsxKTklNc3dwzMrOyc3L7@gsCg4JDQsPKKyCqIArJIrEY85aYk5xalcBaVV@C0CKqgiaEQUIRVR@C0JIKQgOSkRv0cA)

Gets the ordinal values of the uppercased string and checks if they are in strictly increasing order.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 42 bytes

```php
for(;$c=_&$argn[$i++];$p=$c)$c<$p&&die(1);
```

exits with `1` (error) for falsy, exit code `0` for truthy.
Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7815d389383554d1d7f031706f61579851247835).

If you absolutely need visible output, take these 51 bytes:

```php
for(;$c=_&$argn[$i++];$p=$c)$c<$p&&die("0");echo 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ŒuQ⁼ṢƊ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opNLAR417Hu5cdKzr////BaVRAA)

### Explanation

```
ŒuQ⁼ṢƊ Main link: takes string on the left
Œu     uppercase the input
     Ɗ fork: f(x) g h(x)
  Q    unique
   ⁼   equals
    Ṣ  sorted?
```

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 37 bytes

```clj
#(apply < 0(map int(.toLowerCase %)))
```

If it is okay to throw an error on empty strings, we can save 2 bytes by getting rid of the 0.

```clj
#(apply <(map int(.toLowerCase %)))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
LDḳ=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWy3xcHu7YbLukOCm5GCq0YHFBaRWECQA)

##### Explanation

```python
LDḳ=  # Implicit input
L     # Lowercase the input
 D    # Duplicate this string
  ḳ   # Sort and uniquify
   =  # Are they equal?
      # Implicit output
```